# React native compilation takes long time. How to make it faster?

Tags: android, react-native

The app we are working on is a news portal: list of news/articles, photos, videos, charts and the usual stuffs.
A friend created the project skeleton. So far, the features that are already implemented are displaying list of photos and videos. After cloning his repo (RN 0.70), these are what I do:

```
$ npm install
$ npm i react-native-gradle-plugin
$ npx react-native run-android 
$ npm react-native run-android --mode debug --active-arch-only
```

`npx react-native run-android` took more than 1.5 hours (involving downloading and setting up NDK). It was practically stuck at 99%, so I Ctrl-C-ed it. Then I tried `npm react-native run-android --mode debug --active-arch-only`. Took more than 30 minutes and the app isn't running yet. Seems like a red flag for me. My test phone, Pixel 3, still have around 12 GB of free storage.

How can I speed up the building process? I'm on MacOS and don't have any AV running. BTW, I mostly write Kotlin and Java, and not familiar with React Native environment.